# Comparing dicts of lists made from dicts Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sorry for the confusion this problem can cause you.

I have a dict which keys are country names and values that are lists of dicts, see example below:

`{'spain': [{'gold': 3}, {'silver': 1}, {'bronze': 0}], 'colombia': [{'gold': 2}, {'silver': 0}, {'bronze': 0}]}`

I need to compare them and get the one that has more gold medals, but I don't know any way of doing it.

PS: I need to return the country with the most medals in the same way as above:

`{'country':[{'gold':3}, {'silver':3}, {'bronze':3}]}`

Edit: Clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a custom `key` function:

```
dict([max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]['gold'])])
# {'spain': [{'gold': 3}, {'silver': 1}, {'bronze': 0}]}
```